# how to change default package naming for entity, view, and application Module in JDeveloper ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

how to make package name for entity be entity.pkg automatically for new entities, and to be view.pkg for views and AM.pkg for application module without interact by me every time I start "create business component from table" wizard.

Comment: What did you already try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new Jdeveloper workspace from scratch, before running the wizard, go and change `Preferences` → `ADF BC Components` → `Packages`.